# Insert HTML code to the page template via Sitecore CMS

Tags: google-analytics, sitecore, sitecore6, google-tag-manager

I need to insert Google Tag Manager invocation code to a website powered with Sitecore CMS 6.3 – how do I do that? It it possible without the source code, recompiling and deploying the project? Is it doable at the CMS level? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe  http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Google_Analytics.aspx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend on how your site was implemented, but this is most likely not doable at the CMS level.  You are supposed to put the code for the tag container immediately after the opening body tag.  Most sites are not set up to insert arbitrary code at that location.

You do not necessarily need to do a recompile.  You could just add the code to your main layout aspx file.  However, your organization's deployment process may (and hopefully does) require that even this minor change go through the full build and deploy process.